# Igraph Write Communities

Tags: r, csv, igraph, data-analysis

We are using igraph and R to detect communities in a network. The detection using cluster_walktrap is working great:

```
e <- cluster_walktrap(g)

com <-membership(e)

print(com)

write.csv2(com, file ="community.csv", sep=",")
```

The result is printed fine using print with the number and the community number that it belongs to but we have a problem in writing the result in the csv file and I have an error : cannot coerce class ""membership"" to a data.frame

How can I write the result of membership in a file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Convert the `membership` object to `numeric`. `write.csv` and `write.csv2` expect a data frame or matrix. The command tries to coerce the object into a data frame, which the class `membership` resists. Since membership really is just a vector, you can convert it a numeric. Either:

```
write.csv2(as.numeric(com), file ="community.csv")
```

Or:

```
com <- as.numeric(com)
write.csv2(com, file ="community.csv")
```

Oh, and you don't need the `sep = ","` argument for `write.csv`.

If you want to create table of vertex names/numbers and groups:

```
com <- cbind(V(g),e$membership) #V(g) gets the number of vertices
com <- cbind(V(g)$name,e$membership) #To get names if your vertices are labeled
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to have two columns with the number and the community. How can I have that ?

Comment: Working great thank you. Another quick question, if we have more than 100 Million data to analyse then we don't get any data and no error on the log, Is igraph not adapted for big dataset ? (working perfectly for a small dataset)

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/sna-with-r-loading-large-networks-using-the-igraph-library/). I have never personally worked with anything nearly that large. I believe igraph can handle it, but it might not be perfect. Pajek is a non-R program for Windows that is supposed to work with large data. Never used it myself.

Comment: well everything is working fine but the command "com <- cbind(V(g),e$membership)" is blocking when we have a very large file and no result at the end and no error in the log.. Very confusing

Comment: Hm. Try either (1) coercing it to a data frame, `com <- as.data.frame(cbind(V(g),e$membership))`, or (2) create vector of vertex ids and then create a data frame before passing to `write.csv`, `v <- as.numeric(V(g)); com <- data.frame(vertex = v, memb = e$membership)`.

Comment: Thank you. the problem is apparently coming from e <- cluster_walktrap(g)
that does not accept a large dataset (more than 100 Million). do you have an idea about that problem ?

Comment: Try `cluster_fast_greedy`. It is supposed to be optimized for large graphs: see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0408187.pdf). Still, you graph might be too large! Could be exponential time before the algorithm calculate. But see what the paper says.

Comment: We modified the graph to be non oriented then applied cluster_fast_greedy but we have this error : Fast greedy community finding works only on graphs without multiple edges invalid value

Comment: @Omar: Pass your graph to `simplify()` to create a new graph object that is not multiplex. You can use `is_simple()` to see if it is currently multiplex.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you guys resolved the problem but I did the following using R:

````
```
# applying the community method
com = spinglass.community(graph_builted,
                        weights = graph_builted$weights,
                        implementation = "orig", 
                        update.rule = "config")

# creating a data frame to store the results
type = c(0)
labels = c(0)
groups = c(0)
res2 = data.frame(type, labels, groups)   

labels = com$names             # here you get the vertices names
groups = com$membership        # here you get the communities indices 

# here you save the information
res = data.frame(type = "spinGlass1", labels, groups)
res2 = rbind(res2, res) 

# then you save the .csv file 
write.csv(res2, "spinglass-communities.csv")

```
````

That resolves the problem for me.
Best regards.